# Listener / Observable implementation, synchronized vs concurrent collections

Tags: java, concurrency

When implementing thread-safe listeners I usually wonder which type of `Collection` is the best to hold the listeners. I've found three options so far.

The standard `Observable` uses `synchronized` access to a simple `ArrayList`. Using a copy of the listeners is optional but as far as I can tell a good idea since it prevents problems like

- Listener removes itself in callback (`ConcurrentModificationException` - could iterate via indexed `for` loop in inverse order to prevent that)
- Executing external code inside synchronized block can block the entire thing.

Implementation is unfortunately more than a few lines. `Collections.synchronizedList()` would not require `synchronized` in `removeListener` but that's not really worth it.

```
class ObservableList {
    private final List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();
    public void addListener(Listener listener) {
        synchronized (listeners) {
            if (!listeners.contains(listener)) {
                listeners.add(listener);
            }
        }
    }
    public void removeListener(Listener listener) {
        synchronized (listeners) {
            listeners.remove(listener);
        }
    }
    protected void notifyChange() {
        Listener[] copyOfListeners;
        synchronized (listeners) {
            copyOfListeners = listeners.toArray(new Listener[listeners.size()]);
        }
        // notify w/o synchronization
        for (Listener listener : copyOfListeners) {
            listener.onChange();
        }
    }
}
```

But there are `Collection`s in `java.util.concurrent` that are inherently thread-safe and potentially more efficient since I would assume that their internal locking mechanism is optimized better than a simple `synchronized` block. Creating a copy for every notification is also quite expensive.

Based on `CopyOnWriteArrayList`

```
class ObservableCopyOnWrite {
    private final CopyOnWriteArrayList<Listener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    public void addListener(Listener listener) {
        listeners.addIfAbsent(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(Listener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    protected void notifyChange() {
        for (Listener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onChange();
        }
    }
}
```

Should do roughly what the first version does but with less copies. Adding / removing listeners is not a very frequent action which means that copies should not be very frequent as well.

The version I usually use is based on `ConcurrentHashMap` which states for `.keySet()` which is used as `Set` here:

> The view's iterator is a "weakly consistent" iterator that will never throw ConcurrentModificationException, and guarantees to traverse elements as they existed upon construction of the iterator, and may (but is not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.

Which means that iteration includes at least every listener that was registered when starting the iteration and may even include new ones that were added during iteration. Not sure about listeners that were removed. I do like this version because it's not copying and as simple to implement as `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

```
class ObservableConcurrentSet {
    private final Set<Listener> listeners = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Listener, Boolean>());

    public void addListener(Listener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(Listener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    protected void notifyChange() {
        for (Listener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onChange();
        }
    }
}
```

Is a `ConcurrentHashMap` based implementation a good idea or did I overlook something here? Or is there an even better `Collection` to use?

Comment: The CopyOnWrites are perfect for this.  Why not use them?

Comment: @Gray does race mean that adding / removing could result in some other Listener is not seen during iteration? Like initially `{ a, b, c }`, adding `d` while iterating and iteration will only see `{ a, b, d }`. Or does it guarantee that elements that are not touched are seen during iteration. Not / still seeing those that are touched during iteration is fine.

Comment: No, never that.  You might not see `d` in the iteration but you will always see the elements that existed when the iterator was created unless you remove them.

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer.

Comment: do you know how rxjava does this? propagate `onNext()` etc to all its subscribers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is a ConcurrentHashMap based implementation a good idea or did I overlook something here? Or is there an even better Collection to use?

`ConcurrentHashMap` seems to be to be fine in this case. It certainly is better than using `Collections.synchronizedList()`.  The CHM iterator may or may not see new  entries in the map if they are added while the iterator is walking the map.  It also may or may not see old entries if they are deleted during iteration.  Both of these are due to race conditions as to when the nodes in question were added/removed and where the iterator is positioned.  But the iterator will always see items that were in the map when it began as long as they were not deleted.

Comment: Though a ConcurrentHashMap is reasonable, why not a CopyOnWrite collection?  From what I can see, they are perfectly suited to the task.

Comment: I think it could work but in a multithreaded environment, why not use CHP?  If there are few updates then the COW would prolly win but it would not scale well I suspect @user949300.

Comment: I believe COW would have significantly better performance for reads, since basically no locking is required.  And, for Listener type stuff, reads (firing the events) are generally much much more common than writes (adding a listener).

Comment: @user949300 COW seems to be better than I initially through, I guess I'll have to create some sort of testcase to check what kind of datastructure performs best

Answer (score 2):

There is a pattern that outperforms all of these variants since Java 1.1. Look at the `AWTEventMulticaster` class and how it works. It offers thread-safety through immutability and has therefore no additional overhead. It even provides the most efficient way to handle the case when there is no or exactly one listener. Well, I think it offers the most efficient event delivery in general.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AWTEventMulticaster.html

Look into the source code of this class if you want to know how to implement such pattern for own event types.

It is a pity that the Swing developer did not know about this and created that awful EventListenerList leading developers on a wrong path.

And by the way this pattern also solves the problem that listeners added during event delivery should not see the currently delivered event(s) which occurred before the addition. For free. Since Java 1.1

Comment: Interesting.. a dynamic tree of `AWTEventMulticaster`s with listeners as leaf nodes. I'll dig into that and see If I can use that

Comment: There are two downsides. A) you can add listeners more than once. Not a big problem (if at all) and a check could be added. B) It's not easy to use as a generic pattern since the multi cast node that forwards events to it's children must extend the listener interface so it is interchangeable with a simple listener. For a generic implementation for some Listener `T` one would need a `class EventMulticaster implements T` to achieve that. Should be doable via [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html), maybe by a thin implementation each time.

Comment: In principle such a multicaster could be generated on-the-fly similar to how `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` works. However, normally the event type is known at compile time and the number of listener types is finite. So it’s no problem to create the necessary multicaster statically. It would be possible to create an editor macro if the number of listener types deserves it.

Comment: I guess it would be possible to create a generic tree structure based on the principle of `final` linked nodes. The thing that makes it safe is that every modification replaces the root node of the tree. Somewhat similar to a linked list that replaces the head and once you started to iterate from whatever head you currently see you are guaranteed that the tail does not change. In the example given in `AWTEventMultiCaster` I think it would be required that `ActionListener actionListener = null;` is volatile or `processEvent` synchronized as well or you are not guaranteed to see a change.

Comment: That’s right. But since concurrent changes to the listeners are rather unlikely I prefer using an `AtomicReference` or `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater` and no `synchronized` at all. But, surely, that implies a `volatile` field in either case.